# What is the correct way to solve the "never" error in a function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have been trying to solve the problem with typescript for a long time. I have a function that creates a copy of an object and expands one of the arrays. But here I get an error

TS2345: Argument of type 'TFootnote' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

the error appears at this location ...push(footnote)

I can't figure out what exactly he doesn't like. I will be grateful for help.

```
export type TCellData = {
  unitName: string;
  decimals: number;
  domain: string;
  fieldX: string;
  fieldY: string;
  footnotes: TFootnote[] | [];
};

export type TFootnote = {
  item1: string;
  item2: string;
};

    export const justFunction = (
      obj: TCellData,
      footnote: TFootnote
    ) => {
      const newObj = obj;
      newObj?.footnotes?.push(footnote);
    
      return newObj;
    };
```

Comment: Why is `footnotes` of type `TFootnote[] | []` as opposed to just `TFootnote[]`?  The former means "an array that can hold `TFootnote` entries or an array which will always and forever be completely empty" while the latter means "an array that can hold `TFootnote` entries".  I can't see why you'd prefer the first one.

Comment: You're also not doing what you think you're doing. `const newObj = obj` does not create a copy of the original object, it just gives another name to the existing object.  If you want to make a copy you'll need to do it yourself manually.  This is distracting from your question as asked, since it has nothing to do with `never`.  Could you please modify the question to provide a [mre] of your issue without bringing in extra stuff about object copying?

Comment: Additionally `newObj?.footnotes?.push(footnote)` uses the optional chaining operator (`?.`) for no obvious reason.  What are you trying to express here that can't be done with just `newObj.footnotes.push(footnote)`? Could you remove that too?

Comment: If I fix all of your problems at once I get [this code](https://tsplay.dev/N91JMN), but it's not clear how to get from your question to this code as a single answer to a single question.  If you'd like to keep this question open and get an answer, I suggest that you [edit] to make the code example as minimal as possible, perhaps like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mM4RbN)?  And then the answer is from my first comment: "don't union your array type with the empty tuple type. Arrays are allowed to be empty, but the empty tuple *must* be empty so you can't `push()` to it"

Comment: @jcalz you are absolutely right. I looked at the problem from the wrong angle. Thanks a lot. Now everything works correctly and I began to better understand how to perform such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

@jcals gave the correct answer. The whole design was wrong at first. Many thanks to him for his help!

```
export type TCellData = {
  unitName: string;
  decimals: number;
  domain: string;
  fieldX: string;
  fieldY: string;
  footnotes: TFootnote[];
};

export type TFootnote = {
  item1: string;
  item2: string;
};

export const justFunction = (
  obj: TCellData,
  footnote: TFootnote
): TCellData => ({ ...obj, footnotes: [...obj.footnotes, footnote] });
```